# How to create a Mui styled clip which support children

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

How to create a styled chip that supports both single declaration and nested declaration?. I have the following **MUI v5** styled chip.

```
interface StyledModalChipProps {
 theme: Theme
 children: React.ReactNode
}

export const StyledModalChip = styled(Chip)<StyledModalChipProps>(
 ({theme}) => ({
  margin: 5,
  padding: 2,
  borderRadius: 10,
  height: 'fit-content',
  display: 'flex',
  justifyContent: 'center',
  textAlign: 'center',
  alignItems: 'center',
  color: theme.palette.primary.contrastText,
  backgroundColor: theme.palette.primary.main,
  // Style the label
  '& .MuiChip-label': {
   fontWeight: 700,
   fontSize: '1.1rem',
  },
 })
)
```

Fix this as well, and I want to be able to use it in two separate cases like this.

```
// Case 1 directly with labe
<StyledModalChip label="Custom Data" />

// Case 2 nested label with icon
<StyledModalChip>
 <LocalHospitalIcon />
 <Typography>Go to emergerny</Typography>
</StyledModalChip>
```

The current style is error out showing:

```
Type 'Element' is not assignable to type 'null | undefined'.ts(2322)
Chip.d.ts(24, 5): The expected type comes from property 'children' which is
declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { avatar?: ReactElement<any,
 string
 |
 JSXElementConstructor<any
 >> | undefined; children?: null | undefined; ... 12 more ...; variant?:
 OverridableStringUnion<...> | undefined; } & CommonProps & Omit<...> &
 MUIStyledCommonProps<...>'</any,
```

Comment: If I'm correct. Then, you want to use the `StyledModalChip` component in two different ways: one with a label prop and another with nested children, Right.

Comment: Why are you not using like this: `<Chip icon={<FaceIcon />} label="With Icon" />` if you only want to add **icon** and **label**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in the down below image, **Mui** `chip` doesn't support `children`:- [**Mui Chip APIs ref.**](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/chip/)

[image]

And also it clearly said that if you want to use children. Then, you need to the component.

> Use the component prop if you need to change the children structure.

```
<StyledModalChip>
  <LocalHospitalIcon/>
  <Typography>Go to emergerny</Typography>
</StyledModalChip>
```

So, you can use label to parse children. which means you can pass more complex JSX or even other components as the label. Some things like this:

```
export const StyledModalChip = styled(({ children, ...props }: StyledModalChipProps) => (
  <Chip label={children} {...props} />  
))(({ theme }) => ({
// your styles.
}));
```

Now you can use this code:

```
<StyledModalChip>
  <LocalHospitalIcon/>
  <Typography>Go to emergerny</Typography>
</StyledModalChip>
```